# Ros Scan Topic generation by simulator

Tags: turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow some examples looking at the data generated by the Lidar on my simulated turtlebot.

From my investigation, I believe what I am looking for is a modification of one of these launch files: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/tree/master/turtlebot3_gazebo/launch

The desired outcome is: the space with the hexagon of obstacles, plus a TB3 Robot simulator that subscribes to /cmd_vel topics, and that includes a simulated LIDAR data stream publishing /scan topics

Am I on the right track? And if so, how do I edit the launch file to achieve that?

THANKS!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268716/ros-scan-topic-generation-by-simulator/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will answer my own question. I believe this launch file will do what he (i) want(ed):

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2018-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0